# Invalid access on Mongo 3.0

Tags: mongodb

Problem happened in Development site. Following query crashes server with Invalid access at 0x20:

```
db['2015-04-13'].group({
    key:{id:1},
    cond:{created_at:{$gte: new Date('2015-04-13')}},
    reduce:function (curr, resul) {},
    initial: {}
})
```

Traceback:

```
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal2OS8AllocateEmPmb+0xD7) [0x11dbe57]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal28CreateTranscendentalFunctionENS0_19TranscendentalCache4TypeE+0x26) [0x12799f6]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal22init_fast_sin_functionEv+0xE) [0x11dca1e]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal14POSIXPostSetUpEv+0x9) [0x11dd009]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal2V828InitializeOncePerProcessImplEv+0x3E) [0x12551de]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal12CallOnceImplEPlPFvPvES2_+0x52) [0x11c2c12]
 mongod(_ZN2v88internal2V810InitializeEPNS0_12DeserializerE+0x11) [0x1255911]
 mongod(_ZN2v86LockerC1EPNS_7IsolateE+0x61) [0x12597c1]
```

So far i know:
 Problem occurs only when mongod runs as it's own user (mongod). 
If mongod started as root on same data folder, query passes and return results. Number of documents in collection is fairly small (around 20k), but there is decent number of keys for each - 50 in average, and 300 at most, most of them Strings with very few BSONs. MongoDB version is 3.0.2, query was passed as though local client with same version as server, as though 2.4.0 Robomongo client on remote machine - error appears in both cases.

Comment: since it doesn't happen with root I see a couple of possibilities - the mongod user is running out of resources (root has no limits) or by running as root you may have screwed up permissions in the data folder and the mongod user is then hitting files it can't access in the data folder and dying as a result.  Seeing the full logs up to the point of the crash and the output of `ls -al` would be helpful

Comment: ulimits set in limits.conf according to documentation. mongod is owner of data folder and all of it's content. root was never used prior that problem to run mongo.

Comment: File a SERVER ticket in the MongoDB JIRA, with detailed info about the crash.